# Does a granite pestel need to be re-grooved?

Tags: equipment, grinding, mortar-and-pestle

I have a granite Mortar-Pestle, which I use to grind spices and other stuff. I got it 2nd hand and I've been using it for a 3-4 months. I have noticed that the small radial groves on the grinding surface of the pestel are slowly disappearing.

Do I need to re-grove the pestle? If so how is it done? I can't seem to find any information about that on the internet.

Comment: Remember, if the stone is wearing out, you are eating the stone chips and dust. Dentists just LOVE that :-)

Comment: I have an alumina mortar and pestle ; they are very smooth and work well for grinding. They do produce small particles .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just to clarify, the mortar is the bowl and the pestle is the rod. I haven't ever seen a grooved pestle, but the grooves on a mortar will wear off with use. The grooves are useful for holding seeds and the like in place while grinding, but they are not strictly necessary. Spices can actually be ground finer in a smooth mortar than they can with a grooved one since the particles can't get caught in the ridges, however the initial grinding and tapping may take slightly longer to get started as you chase things like seeds around the bowl a little. The rough surface of the granite alone is enough, just adjust your technique as it wears more.

Comment: OK. I will try to put a picture of grooves on the bottom of the pestel if I can find one..

Comment: Nice one. But this one seemed to have smaller and less deep radial groves outwards from the center of the pestle.